# HDFStore with string columns gives issues

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pytables

I have a pandas DataFrame `myDF` with a few string columns (whose `dtype` is `object`) and many numeric columns. I tried the following:

```py
d=pandas.HDFStore("C:\\PF\\Temp.h5")
d['test']=myDF
```

I got this result:

```text
C:\PF\WinPython-64bit-3.3.3.3\python-3.3.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py:2446: PerformanceWarning: 

your performance may suffer as PyTables will pickle object types that it cannot
map directly to c-types [inferred_type->mixed,key->block2_values] 
[items->[0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 292, ...]]

warnings.warn(ws, PerformanceWarning)
```

It seems like the issue is occurring for every column that is a string. For example if I try

```py
myDF[0].dtype
```

I get

```text
Out[38]: dtype('O')
```

How can I fix the issue, i.e. change the `dtype` for string columns so that HDFStore can treat it like a string column?

---

**EDIT**

More info as requested

```
>>> pandas.__version__
Out[49]: '0.13.1'

>>> tables.__version__
Out[53]: '3.1.0'
```

Constructing the pandas data frame as follows:

```py
pandas.read_csv(fName,sep="|",header=None, low_memory=False)
```

When I try

```py
myDF.info()
```

I get

```text
Int64Index: 153895 entries, 0 to 153894
Data columns (total 644 columns):
0      object
1      object
2      int64
3      object
4      object
5      object
6      object
7      int64
8      float64
9      object
10     object
11     float64
12     float64
...
...
642    float64
643    float64
dtypes: float64(619), int64(2), object(23)
```

All string columns have been read as `object`.

Comment: can u show pandas version, pytables version, os, df.info(), how constructed the df, and a sample

Comment: why are you passing ``low_memory``? do you have unicode in any strings?

Comment: because the file is too large, and without `low_memory` it doesn't seem to work. Here is the error `C:\PF\WinPython-64bit-3.3.3.3\python-3.3.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py:1070: DtypeWarning: Columns (6,292,479,572,581,590,599,608,617,626,635) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
  data = self._reader.read(nrows)`

Comment: ok, are you on 32-bit? read in by chunks, and create a ``table`` store instead.

Comment: no, I am on 64-bit. see error above. Also, what do you mean by a `table` store?

Comment: you are creating a ``fixed`` store, see here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#hdf5-pytables

Comment: but your problem is not that really, its the mixed dtypes in a column.  read in by chunks then either append to a list and concat, or append as you go to a ``table`` store. mixed types in a column are really bad

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#iterating-through-files-chunk-by-chunk

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20428355/appending-column-to-frame-of-hdf-file-in-pandas/20428786#20428786

Comment: don't use ``low_memory`` flag, its not documented because it allows columns to have mixed dtypes, you never want that.

Comment: thanks, the `fixed` store option works. is there a way to convert any column with apparently mixed types to be treated as strings when using `read_csv`??

Comment: I updated the answer; you can do it after you read it in

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This warning ONLY happens if you have mixed-types IN a column. Not just strings, but string AND numbers.

```
In [2]: DataFrame({ 'A' : [1.0,'foo'] }).to_hdf('test.h5','df',mode='w')
pandas/io/pytables.py:2439: PerformanceWarning: 
your performance may suffer as PyTables will pickle object types that it cannot
map directly to c-types [inferred_type->mixed,key->block0_values] [items->['A']]

  warnings.warn(ws, PerformanceWarning)

In [3]: df = DataFrame({ 'A' : [1.0,'foo'] })

In [4]: df
Out[4]: 
     A
0    1
1  foo

[2 rows x 1 columns]

In [5]: df.dtypes
Out[5]: 
A    object
dtype: object

In [6]: df['A']
Out[6]: 
0      1
1    foo
Name: A, dtype: object

In [7]: df['A'].values
Out[7]: array([1.0, 'foo'], dtype=object)
```

So, you need to ensure that you don't mix WITHIN a column

If you have columns that need conversion you can do this:

```
In [9]: columns = ['A']

In [10]: df.loc[:,columns] = df[columns].applymap(str)

In [11]: df
Out[11]: 
     A
0  1.0
1  foo

[2 rows x 1 columns]

In [12]: df['A'].values
Out[12]: array(['1.0', 'foo'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: is there any option in `read_csv` to specify it to treat any column as string if it is appears as MIXED?

Comment: I tried `df.loc[:,columns] = df[columns].applymap(str)` but it did not change the `dtype` in my case from `object` to string. Even in your example, the `dtype` doesn't change from `object` to string

Comment: dtype won't change, it will still be ``object``. The embeded values will be strings though. THAT's the problem. In the data you are reading the embeded objects are float/ints (actual python objects), and NOT strings. So when the frame is being written to the store, they are objects and NOT strings (and that is why you get the warning)

Comment: For blanks, or NaN, this outputs nan as a string which is actually shown in the file (not desired). Should I replace those with np.nan or will that cause the column to be an object again? Or should I use a fillna('Blank') or something? It seems like that will eat up space, but then again I have a lot of space.